# SQL returning 1 single column value on a multiple row

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my query so far. But what I need is to return one single value of a column like this.
[image]

But in my query so far, this is the returning output.
[image]

This my query.

How can I get rid of the double values?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
                sol.order_id,
                so.name as so_number,
                DATE(so.requested_date + INTERVAL '8 HOURS') as delivery_date,
                us.name as sales_executive,
                rp.partner_type as account_type,
                rp.name as account_name,
                pt.name as sku,
                sol.price_unit as price,
                sol.product_uom_qty as ordered_qty,
                sol.actual_delivered as delivered_qty,
                rb.return_qty,
                so.amount_total as gross_sales,
                ai.amount_untaxed as vatable_sales,
                ai.amount_tax as vat,
                ai.residual as net_sales
            FROM sale_order so
            LEFT JOIN res_partner rp ON rp.id = so.partner_id
            LEFT JOIN res_users ru ON ru.id = so.user_id
            LEFT JOIN res_partner us ON us.id = ru.partner_id
            LEFT JOIN sale_order_line sol ON sol.order_id = so.id
            LEFT JOIN product_template pt ON pt.id = sol.product_id
            LEFT JOIN account_invoice ai ON ai.origin = so.name
            LEFT JOIN return_bottle rb ON rb.sale_id = so.id
            WHERE DATE(so.requested_date + INTERVAL '8 HOURS') >= '2020-12-01' 
            AND DATE(so.requested_date + INTERVAL '8 HOURS') <= '2020-12-30' 
            AND ai.state != 'cancel'
            AND so.name = 'SO11156'
            GROUP BY sol.order_id, so.name, rb.return_qty, delivery_date, us.name, rp.partner_type, rp.name, pt.name, sol.price_unit, sol.product_uom_qty, sol.actual_delivered, so.amount_total, ai.amount_untaxed, ai.amount_tax, ai.residual
            ORDER BY delivery_date ASC, SOL.ORDER_ID
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How can I get rid of the double values?

Comment: @AndrywinMaquinto . . . In an aggregation query, the `GROUP BY` defines the unique rows in the result set.  If you want one row per order id, that should be (essentially) the only column in the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytical function as follows:

Let's say the column you highlighted is `sol.actual_delivered` then use the following expression instead of `sol.actual_delivered`

```
case when row_number() over (partition by sol.order_id, so.name order by so.requested_date) = 1
    then sol.actual_delivered 
end as actual_delivered
```

Answer (score 0):

The DISTINCT will go display  diferents rows for the set of columns defined in select, when at least one have distinct value. In your case you should remove the third column of command  select or define in query  that  alawys will get the first value. But this can generate diferents query result for  each run of query.

EX: col1 col2 col3

```
 1    2    3
 1    4    3
```

- Remove the column col2 because have distinct values

  SELECT DISTINCT col1, col3 FROM tab
- Result
  col1   col3
  1      3
- Keeping col2

  select distinct col1, (select col2 from tab t where t.id = s.id limit 1 as col2,col3 from tab s ;
- Results

  col1 col2  col3
  1    2    3

  ```
  OR
  ```

  col1 col2  col3
  1    4    3